# AWS Bucket Undeletable

Tags: amazon-s3

The AWS S3 web console lists buckets that were deleted. Selecting the bucket and trying to empty or delete it causes the "Empty bucket" or "Delete bucket" modal Confirm button to fail silently.

If you click into the bucket and try to upload a file, you get an error message, "Error Data not found". If you try to create a folder, you get, "Error Failed to create folder with name ''." If you try to change and Property, Permissions, or Management, you also get error messages.

If you try to create a bucket with the same name (presumably to overwrite the old bucket), you get an error message indicating that the bucket name is taken.

Libraries such as s3-upload are similarly unable to delete or overwrite the bucket.

AWS (Node) SDK:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new aws.S3();

s3.listBuckets({}, (error, data) => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(data);
});
```

returns the bucket, even though it should not exist.

```
{ 
  Buckets: [ 
   { Name: 'bucket.that.shouldnt.exist', CreationDate: 2017-02-20T01:51:19.000Z },
  ],
  Owner: { 
   DisplayName: '...',
   ID: '...' 
  }     
}
```

and

```
s3.deleteBucket({
  Bucket: 'bucket.that.shouldnt.exist'
}, (error, data) => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(data);
});
```

returns

```
{ 
  NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist
  at Request.extractError (.../aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:585:35)
  at Request.callListeners (.../aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
  at Request.emit (.../aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
  at Request.emit (.../aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
  at Request.transition (.../aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
  at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (.../aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
  at .../aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
  at Request.<anonymous> (.../aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
  at Request.<anonymous> (.../aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
  at Request.callListeners (.../aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message: 'The specified bucket does not exist',
  code: 'NoSuchBucket',
  region: null,
  time: 2019-06-04T16:56:35.537Z,
  requestId: '...',
  extendedRequestId: '...',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 404,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 33.90621042754991 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is a large-scale, distributed system. Deleting an S3 bucket is quite different to deleting a local folder on your hard drive.

After you initiate the deletion of a bucket, the bucket name becomes unavailable for a certain amount of time. You cannot re-create the bucket, re-delete the bucket, get objects from the bucket, or put objects to the bucket.

The amount of time that a recently-deleted bucket name cannot be reused to create a new bucket varies. If you owned the bucket name previously and you are trying to re-create the bucket in the same region then you can typically re-create it almost immediately. If you are not the previous owner or you are trying to re-create the bucket name in a different region then the bucket name will typically be unavailable for hours.

Note that as a general rule, if you intend to re-use the same bucket name then it is typically better to simply empty the bucket rather than delete and re-create the bucket. Another customer could create the same-named bucket between your deletion and re-creation attempts, thus causing you to lose control of the bucket name (unlikely, of course, but possible).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the AWS createBucket API worked (although the console did not):

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new aws.S3();

s3.createBucket({
  Bucket: 'bucket.that.shouldnt.exist'
}, (error, data) => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(data);
});
```

then, you should be able to perform operations normally on the overwritten bucket.